# Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Tags: java, sockets, netbeans

I have problem with server/client project.I am trying to make an app for summation of two numbers but NetBeans show me exception when I start client part.I tried to change port number but result is same.
[image: client]

[image: server]

Comment: Perhaps you have a previous instance running, and It doesn't realease the port yet.

Comment: are you running 2 instances of the programm at once?

Comment: Don't post code as images. Post it as text. But anyway, the code here doesn't matter. You're simply trying to listen to a port that another process already listens on, probably another instance of your server.

Comment: At the bottom we can see you ran the program before. I guess it didnt terminate yet and thus blocks the port 8080.